# Logic error in minimax implementation

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm working on an artificial intelligence program to play a board game. The trouble is that my implementation of the minimax algorithm has a serious error somehow that I've been trying to figure for a couple of days now and still haven't managed to figure it out.

It's doing my nut in so I'd appreciate it if someone could have a look at my code and see why it's not terminating properly.

When I run it it appears to correctly search the tree and terminate when it reaches the final depth but for some reason it can't search the of the deepest layer and forever finds more nodes to search (which is theoretically impossible).

I have covered all the rest of the code with unittests and it's all working. However my unittests on this part don't ever work because it just endlessly executes without terminating.

If there is any information that can help I can provide it.

Thanks

```
def recursive_minimax(self, board, depth, player_id):
    #there are no more moves possible so the game is over
    if board.get_available_moves(player_id)==[]:
        return 1 if player_id == self.max_player else -1

    #check to ensure correct depth has been passed into method
    if depth>self.depth:
        raise ValueError("Impossible value for depth")

    #if max depth reached calculate estimated node value
    if depth == 0:
        return self.eval_func(board, player_id)

    if player_id == self.max_player:
        best_val = -999
        moves = board.get_available_moves(player_id)

        for move in moves:
            new_board = board.make_move(move, player_id, True)
            opposing_player = board.get_opposing_player(player_id)

            val = self.recursive_minimax(new_board, depth - 1, opposing_player)
            best_val = max(val, best_val)


    else:
        best_val = 999
        moves = board.get_available_moves(player_id)

        for move in moves:
            #make copy of the board and play move
            new_board = board.make_move(move, player_id, True)
            opposing_player = board.get_opposing_player(player_id)

            val = self.recursive_minimax(new_board, depth - 1, opposing_player)
            best_val = min(val, best_val)

    return best_val
```

Here is the unittest (forgive my sloppiness in the test code):

```
def test_recursive_minimax(self):
    #self.skipTest("recursive error")
    init_board = _make_board(5)

    for tile_id in init_board.keys():
        counters = choice(range(len(init_board[tile_id]["neighbours"])-1))
        init_board[tile_id]["counters"] = counters if counters!= 0 else None
        init_board[tile_id]["player"] = choice([0,1]) if counters!=0 else None

    board=Board(init_board, 0)
    strategy = Minimax(board)

    for tile_id, tile in strategy.board.tiles():
        player = 0 if tile["player"]==None else tile["player"]

        new_board = strategy.board.make_move(tile_id, player)
        value = strategy.recursive_minimax(new_board, 1,player)

        self.assertIsNotNone(value)
        self.assertTrue(0<=value<=1 or value in(999, -999))

    for tile_id, tile in strategy.board.tiles():
        player = 0 if tile["player"]==None else tile["player"]

        new_board = strategy.board.make_move(tile_id, player)
        value = strategy.recursive_minimax(new_board, 2,player)

        self.assertIsNotNone(value)
        self.assertTrue(0<=value<=1 or value in(999, -999))

    for tile_id, tile in strategy.board.tiles():
        player = 0 if tile["player"]==None else tile["player"]

        new_board = strategy.board.make_move(tile_id, player)
        value = strategy.recursive_minimax(new_board, 3,player)

        self.assertIsNotNone(value)
        self.assertTrue(0<=value<=1 or value in(999, -999))
```

the unittest never gets to the assertion because the minimax doesn't terminate

Comment: It would be nice if you'd provide your unit test.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that tobias_k? I think when I call it in the next iteration I pass in the opposing_player from board.get_opposing_player(player_id) but I might be doing something wrong and just unable to see it.

Comment: No, never mind, I just got confused with some subtle differences in your implementation and the pseudocode I used for reference.

Comment: You don't say anything about what board game this is - what the expected depth and fan-out might be. Maybe it's working properly but will take a year to run?

Comment: Cheers Hugh, while that wasn't exactly the problem that certainly helped me solve it. The actual issue is that the make_move method returns false if the game is over but there is no check for this prior to calling it. This only occurred rarely and hence was masked by an error in the way the depth was passed into the method which meant the depth was significantly greater than expected and gave the apparently endless recursion.